# $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\left \lfloor \frac{3\sin(x^2)-1}{2\cos(x)+1} \right \rfloor$=?

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to find this limit:
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\left \lfloor \frac{3\sin(x^2)-1}{2\cos(x)+1} \right \rfloor $$
where $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$ is the floor-function?

Generally, how to find limit of floor-function?
tnx

Comment: Could you find the limit if the floor wasn't there?

Answer (score 3):

Hint. The [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) $t\to\lfloor t\rfloor$ is continuous for $t\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow n^+}\lfloor t\rfloor=n\quad\mbox{and}\quad
\lim_{t \rightarrow n^-}\lfloor t\rfloor=n-1.$$
Evaluate 
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi}\frac{3\sin(x^2)-1}{2\cos(x)+1}.$ Is it an integer number?